# Sketch to XCode Image Size? (baffler)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode5

I'm working with [Sketch](http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/) by Bohemian Coding. It has preset iPhone artboards that include 640x960 and 640x1136, but when I export the images to XCode the size and positions of the images are incorrect. Do I have to resize my images? Is there any way I can create the images in the correct size every time?

Even though the Sketch image is designed for 640x960, in another project I made the images to 640x1136 and it did the same thing.

---

**Screenshots**
[image]

[image]

Comment: Define 'incorrect'. How are they incorrect? Does Xcode complain when you try to use them as launch images?

Comment: I don't have a launch image for when the app opens. Incorrect, meaning that when I put in the positions and sizes for all my images, whether they are buttons, backgrounds, etc., the positions and sizes do not match up with the design in Sketch.

Comment: Ah. It might be helpful, then, to show some screenshots explaining the problem visually.

Comment: Wouldn't this be something to take up with the developers of Sketch?

Comment: They aren't very helpful in the way of support/contacting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the rectangle surrounding 'AC' is the image you're trying to export, it almost looks like the XCode image is twice the size of the original. In which case, are you naming the file with a '@2x.png' suffix?

edit:

So I played around with Sketch, using the `640px by 1136px` preset. Then I checked the `Also export as:` option with both `Double size (@2x)` and `Half size (@1x)` separately. From the basic info Finder reports - What I noticed was this:

```
Generated files suffix ==> "@2x.png"        ".png" (without suffix)
===================
Actual file pixels
"Double size"              1280 x 2272      640 x 1136
"Half size"                640  x 1136      320 x 568
```

Maybe the chart is a little confusing, but from what I can tell, the `Double size` and `Half size` options don't seem to mean anything since the art boards are always generated in retina resolutions anyways. To get the right naming convention for the right resolution, you'll want to use the Half size option, and import the @2x file for retina devices, and the regular png for non-retina devices.

**TL:DR - Use "Also export as: Half size"**

Comment: I designed it for the iPhone 4 size: 640x960 and Sketch is capable of generating the regular and @2x images. But like you observed, they appear to be twice the size. Why doesn't Sketch export correctly? Am I designing based on an incorrect resolution? What resolution should I design in?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a weird workaround:

1. Design for 640x1136 pixels
2. Export as 1/2 size (@1x)
3. Divide the original sketch position/size values by 2 to get the values for XCode